# Most seamless way to present data in gui

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm creating python app using relatively big SQL database (250k rows). Application needs GUI where most important part of it would be to present results of SQL queries.

So I'm looking for a best way to quickly present data in tables in GUI.

Most preferably I'd be using wx - as it has seamless connection to main application I'm working with. And what I need is least effort between SQL query a and populating GUI table. 
I used once wx.grid, but it seemed to be limited functionality. Also I know of wx.grid.pygridtablebase - what is the difference?
What would be easiest way to do this?

Comment: "limited functionality" -- in which way?

Comment: i.e. it doen't cover right click events. Well,actually that's my question - are there any more appropriate classes to do so?

Comment: No, [wxGrid](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxgrid.html) is the way to go. You can most probably bend it to your needs. Right click events are no exception to this (see `EVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use wx.grid or one of the ListCtrls. There's an example of a grid with 100 million cells in the wxPython demo that you could use for guidance on projects with lots of information. For ListCtrls, you would want to use a Virtual ListCtrl using the wx.LC_VIRTUAL flag. There's an example of that in the demo as well.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I know it is possible, but I was wondering if there's some extension of wx.something that has handler to populate grid with SQL query like wx.grid.pasteSQL(cur.fetchall()) , and it'd automatically determine no and names of columns, no of rows, formats, etc.
I made my own classes based on wx.grid, but I hoped I wouldn't need to do so.

Comment: Well you could use Dabo which is a layer on top of wxPython that was built with databases in mind.